# Android multi_touch listener

Tags: java, android, soundpool, multitouch-keyboard

Hi I'm working on an android Java app where I need to play three different sounds with soundpool at the same time using three different buttons.**code in picture
**. I loaded sounds into three buttons but when I click all three at time no sound is played. But it works when i click two buttons. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: put some part of your code

Comment: please put all logic which is inside of three buttons click along with setting ClickListener lines in your question. OR Look https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){                         
 public void onClick(View ,view)             {soundPool.play(button_1,1,1,0,0,1);}    });         button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){                         
 public void onClick(View ,view)             {soundPool.play(button_2,1,1,0,0,1);}    });                                                                            
                                                            
        button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

Answer (score 0):

Use `.setMaxStreams(int maxStreams)` inside `SoundPool.Builder()` method. As this works on api 21 or higher, so you need to set the condition.
i.e.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { // lollipop is constant for api 21
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder() // using instance of audio attributes
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION) // different usage types, press CTRL+B & we get to it's declaration, and we see the description of usage types.
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION) 
                .build();
    soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
        .setMaxStreams(10) //  Sets the maximum of number of simultaneous streams 
                            // that can be played simultaneously.
        .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
        .build();
    }
       else{
         soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I used that, everything is fine with sound but when I click three buttons at a time OnClickLister doesn't work

Comment: Create View otherwise, IT WILL CRASH when you will click on any button. Generate playSound() method and add case switch for certain views by getting their id's.

Comment: Yeah I used that switch statement with view.getId() it work but problem is multi-click(clicking three buttons at a time) doesn't work.

Comment: Have you also used soundPool.autoPause(); inside the case button id of your view.getId()?  [Here soundPool is the declared var of SoundPool i.e. private SoundPool soundPool;]